# SQL Server query to repeat latest value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a combination of `Users` and `Weeks`. The User gets a Score that occurs within a given week. I need help repeating the last available score for a given Week if it's `null`.

I've already tried a number of solutions, including the `LAST_VALUE`

```
SELECT UserId, StartOfWeekDate, Score ,LAST_VALUE(Score) 
OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY StartOfWeekDate ASC) AS LastValue
FROM [ScoresByUserOverWeek]
```

*Currently it looks like this:*

```
UserId  StartOfWeekDate overall LastValue

12534   12/17/2018      NULL    NULL

12534   12/24/2018      NULL    NULL

12534   12/31/2018      320     320

12534   1/7/2019        NULL    NULL

12534   1/14/2019       NULL    NULL

12534   1/21/2019       NULL    NULL

12534   1/28/2019       345     345

12534   2/4/2019        NULL    NULL

12534   2/11/2019       NULL    NULL
```

Expected:

```
UserId  StartOfWeekDate overall LastValue

12534   12/17/2018      NULL    NULL

12534   12/24/2018      NULL    NULL

12534   12/31/2018      320     320

12534   1/7/2019        NULL    320

12534   1/14/2019       NULL    320

12534   1/21/2019       NULL    320

12534   1/28/2019       345     345

12534   2/4/2019        NULL    345

12534   2/11/2019       NULL    345
```

Comment: Inserting the records into a temp table or a table variable and then updating the LastValue in a WHILE will outperform any SQL in this case

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery with a `CASE WHEN` clause to achieve that:

```
SELECT UserId, StartOfWeekDate, Score ,
CASE WHEN Score IS NOT NULL THEN Score ELSE 
(SELECT TOP 1 Score FROM ScoresByUserOverWeek T2 WHERE T1.UserID = T2.UserID AND T1.StartOfWeekDate > T2.StartOfWeekDate  AND T2.Score IS NOT NULL ORDER BY T2.StartOfWeekDate DESC) 
END AS LastValue
FROM ScoresByUserOverWeek T1
```

**Experiments**

```
--Create Table and Insert Values
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (UserId INT, StartOfWeekDate DATETIME, Score INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP (UserId , StartOfWeekDate , Score )

VALUES( 12534 , '20181217' , NULL ),
( 12534, '20181224' , NULL ),
( 12534, '20181231' , 320 ),
( 12534, '20190107' , NULL ),
( 12534, '20190114' , NULL ),
( 12534, '20190121' , NULL ),
( 12534, '20190128' , 345 ),
( 12534, '20190204' , NULL ),
( 12534, '20190211' , NULL )



--Execute Query
SELECT UserId, StartOfWeekDate, Score ,
CASE WHEN Score IS NOT NULL THEN Score ELSE 
(SELECT TOP 1 Score FROM #TEMP T2 WHERE T1.UserID = T2.UserID AND T1.StartOfWeekDate > T2.StartOfWeekDate  AND T2.Score IS NOT NULL ORDER BY T2.StartOfWeekDate DESC) 
END AS LastValue
FROM #TEMP T1
```

*Result*

[image]

Comment: Performance is horrible, but it works. Try to use max  conbined with over(partition by) to maximize your query

Comment: @AlvaroParra I agree that it maybe not performant. But it is not **horrible** as you mentioned